# NFPA70E Question: My company provides electrical inspection services, does my technician need to wear a hot suit?

Tags: safety, code

So my company provides preventative maintenance inspections, wherein the technician will open a large number of electrical panels, rated from 120-480 volts, sometimes up to 30 panelboards in a single facility, transformers as well. I'm trying to push us more and more toward compliance with NFPA 70E, minimize risk, all that. An exception is given in 70E for infrared inspections only, however this does not include removal of covers or voltage testing, which is part of the inspection as well. So hypothetically, he throws on a hot suit, takes the cover off, tests the voltage, takes the hot suit off, makes notes, takes his thermography imaging, puts the hot suit back on, puts the cover back on, and moves to the next panel....30 times. I am hoping to get advice on either better workflow from someone more experienced in this type of work, or if at all possible, a loophole or something. I want my workers to be safe but this kind of expenditure of effort and time wasting, I can only think that we can offer a competitively priced service if I can figure something crafty out. Otherwise we might as well not offer the service.

Comment: If you use the suits give the tec a tape recorder or some other device, maybe a company supplied cell phone.

Comment: Beyond voltage level, It also depends on the power of the panelboard, a house panelboard or a 1MW foundry isn't the same risks, same as if you have highly inductive stuff hooked to it that can create massive arcs. NFPA 70E should cover these subjects.

Comment: For a forum that supports discussion I suggest that you look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements and problems as possible. 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively), and are allowed to discuss anything conversationally. Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Comment: Just watch some arc flash videos on YouTube

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that: yes, that tech needs to wear rated gear to do the activity of removing the panel to take that measurement.  I found a reference chart [here that summarizes the different activates and when arc flash is possible; NFPA 70E Table 130.5(C)](https://arcflash101.webflow.io/lookup-tables/table-130-5-c-likelihood-of-arc-flash-incident).

Because your usage is low voltage there may be able to define the garments required to provide the protection required.  The most reasonable way to approach the PPE is to have arc flash rated clothing and get used to wearing the gloves, ear plugs, hat, and face shield.